# VS2012 assert helper function - test runner should not track in my function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2012, automated-tests

During testing I have several Assert helper functions specific to the project. For example, I have to often check whether two IEnumerables are equivalent (exactly same content by reference, not regarding the order). So have a static class for these. E.g.:

```
internal static class MyAssert
{
    public static void AreEquivalent<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable1, IEnumerable<T> enumerable2)
    {
        bool val = false;
        if (enumerable2 == null)
        {
            val = !enumerable1.Any();
        } else {
            var list1 = enumerable1.ToList();
            var list2 = enumerable2.ToList();

            val = (list1.Count == list2.Count && list1.Intersect(list2).Count() == list2.Count());
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(val);
    }
}
```

Then if I use `MyAssert.AreEquivalent(enumer1, enumer2);`, and it fails, then the whole stack trace is shown inside the helper function. I would like to miss it, so if a developer comes, and sees the source of assert, he only sees that the MyAssert thing failed, but he does not see where was the problem inside my helper function (he cannot do anything with `Assert.IsTrue(val))`.

I know that it can be done with `Assert.IsTrue(MyCollHelper.AreEquivalent(enumer1, enumer2))`, but this is not as readebly as the previous.

Comment: I wonder why you write your own code, as many testing frameworks already provide this functionality, like [nunit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.4.8)

Comment: I need to use builtin VS framework

Comment: You can use [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible now.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure that I understand you correctly. If you or the developer will see which part of your method causes the error than use `Assert.Fail()`. I didn't test it:

```
internal static class MyAssert
{
public static void AreEquivalent<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable1, IEnumerable<T> enumerable2)
{
    bool val = false;
    if (enumerable2 == null)
    {
        val = !enumerable1.Any();

        if (val == false)
        {
            Assert.Fail("enumerable2 is empty, enumerable1 is not");
        }
    }
    else if (enumerable1 == null)
    {
        val = !enumerable2.Any();

        if (val == false)
        {
            Assert.Fail("enumerable1 is empty, enumerable2 is not");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var list1 = enumerable1.ToList();
        var list2 = enumerable2.ToList();

        if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Count result is not the same");
        }

        if (list1.Intersect(list2).Count() != list2.Count())
        {
            Assert.Fail("count of Intersect enumerable1 is not the same as enumerable2 count");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this tactic, but the main aim is not to see inside the helper functions. I am looking for attributes or something like this which prevent that behavior.

Comment: @cslajos I am not quit sure, but I think this is not possible.

Comment: yes, that was my assumption too, I was just courious, whether it can be done (anyway, who edits my comment and puts in grammar errors? i had to delete and write a new)